How can I shade in an arc of a circle like in the image below
I want to make a circe where from the center an arc of 45 degrees is shaded out to the edge of the circe. I will need to change the angle a few times, but to start I would like to do at least 45 degrees and 120 degrees. I have included what I want the images to look like below as well.
I have tried making circles and shading them, I have also tried to make the arc and shade the resulting image, but both approaches did not work. I've tried at least 2 dozen variations of making and shading circles across tikz and tkz-euclide, and have given up.


Welcome. // Please add the code of your best trial. Please take care, we can compile it (\documentclass … {document} ). Thank you

tkz-euclide documentation :  \tkzFillSector  page 145

Here is a basis you can play with.
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\R{2mm}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\startAngle{10}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\valueAngle{45}
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
  \node at ($(O)+(180+\valueAngle:6pt)$) {$O$};
  \draw (O) circle [radius=\R];
  \fill[gray, fill opacity=.6] (O) --++ (\startAngle:\R) node[pos=.5, sloped, below, opacity=1, black] {$\R$} arc [start angle=\startAngle,end angle=\valueAngle+\startAngle,x radius=\R,y radius=\R];
  \node [fill=white,inner sep=2pt,rounded corners] at ($(O)+(\startAngle+\valueAngle*.5:\R*.3)$) {$\qty{\valueAngle}{\degree}$};
  
  % just to check the angles values
  \draw [dashdotted] (O) -- (0:\R);
  \draw [dotted] (O) -- (10:\R);
  \draw [dashed] (O) -- (45:\R);
  \draw [dashdotdotted] (O) -- (55:\R);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Only because I'm curious about using Chatgpt. He makes three mistakes, but we get there! (3cm instead of 3, and he doesn't know \tkzFillSector
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Define points for the center and two endpoints of the arc
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}  % Center of the circle
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){A}  % One endpoint of the arc
    \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center O angle 45](A) \tkzGetPoint{B} % Other endpoint of the arc

    % Draw the circle
    \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)

    % Shade the arc between points A and B
    % \begin{scope}
    %     \fill[blue!30,opacity=0.5] (O) -- (A) arc[start angle=0,end angle=45,radius=3] -- cycle;
    % \end{scope}
    \tkzFillSector[blue!30,opacity=0.5](O,A)(B)

    % Draw the radius lines and arc
    \tkzDrawSegment(O,A)
    \tkzDrawSegment(O,B)
    \tkzDrawArc[thick](O,A)(B)
\end{tikzpicture}



I did originally try to use ChatGPT as well, but I got a different response than what you got, or maybe we got the same response and you changed yours to be correct. I also did not know about \tkzFillSector so I was not able to get there. Thank you for your help!

@KetanI. Yes you are right, I changed the answser (three mistakes ! )
